# how to find paired ECDSA private key PKCS11 having public key

Tags: c#, rsa, bouncycastle, ecdsa, pkcs11interop

I have an application that works with smartcards that have RSA certificates on them
For some reason manufacturer does not fill CKA_LABEL on them, so i fidn private key object for RSA like this:

```
RsaKeyParameters rsaPubKeyParams = (RsaKeyParameters)pubKeyParams;
                    privKeySearchTemplate.Add(session.Factories.ObjectAttributeFactory.Create(CKA.CKA_KEY_TYPE, CKK.CKK_RSA));
                    privKeySearchTemplate.Add(session.Factories.ObjectAttributeFactory.Create(CKA.CKA_MODULUS, rsaPubKeyParams.Modulus.ToByteArrayUnsigned()));
                    privKeySearchTemplate.Add(session.Factories.ObjectAttributeFactory.Create(CKA.CKA_PUBLIC_EXPONENT, rsaPubKeyParams.Exponent.ToByteArrayUnsigned()));
```

now i have to support smartcards that have ECDSA certificates, no CKA_LABEL also
SO the question is how can i find according private key like with RSA ?

Note: all smart cards have 2 certificates (auth,sign) in random order, so i cant just take first or last object found:

```
ECPublicKeyParameters ecdsaPubKeyParams = (ECPublicKeyParameters)pubKeyParams;
                    privKeySearchTemplate.Add(session.Factories.ObjectAttributeFactory.Create(CKA.CKA_KEY_TYPE, CKK.CKK_ECDSA));
```

-----some more params needed to identify the needed the private key

Answer (score 0):

If it is the same curve, you can't.
A workaround would be to test a signature/verification, then if match, assign CLA_LABEL to optimize for next time.

Answer (score 0):

If you set a unique `LABLE` or `ID` for key, you can recover key-pair easily. Then, public key is the one which has `CKA.CKA_VERIFY` attribute as True and private key is the one which has `CKA.CKA_SIGN` attribute set to True.

Another tip: for RSA you have its modules and exponent, for elliptic key you have its ec-point `CKA.CKA_EC_POINT` which is unique for any elliptic-public-key.